# How can i connect DroidCam to processing?

Tags: android-camera, processing

I'm studying processing in my class.
In class, I used laptop webcam to connect video on processing, which was just

void setup() {
 video = new Capture(this,width,height);

But now I want to use my smartphone as a cam, so I installed DroidCam.
While I downloaded DroidCam both on my pc and smartphone, I could see it's connected and working, but I don't know how to change laptop webcam to Droidcam.
I think I have to change ***this*** to something else,

video = new Capture(***this***,width,height);

but I don't know how can I check the names of cameras when there are several cameras connected to my pc.

Comment: Processing's Video library handles USB cameras mainly, not IP cameras: you'll need a library for that. Not 100% sure if it will work, but you can try using the [IPCapture library](http://www.stefanobaldan.com/projects/ipcapture/).

Comment: The `this` parameter refers to the sketch itself, not the camera. You definitely wouldn't want to change that parameter.